# Как переписать код с jquery на vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть такой код...  надо перегнать в яваскрипт  . Проблема с верхней строчкой

```
$('#output').on('input ','.dynamic-Qty', function(e){
    let z = e.target.dataset;
    console.log(z.id)
    console.log(this.value)

    var itemInCart = false;
    console.log(shopcart);
     let qtty = parseInt(this.value);
     if(qtty<0) {qtty = 0;this.value=0;}


    shopcart.forEach((value, index) => {
        console.log(index + ' ' + value.id);
        if (value.id == z.id) {
            shopcart[index].qty= qtty;
            itemInCart = true;
        }
    });

    sessionStorage['shopcart'] = JSON.stringify(shopcart);
    outputCart();
    console.log(sessionStorage['shopcart']);

});
```

Comment: `for (let i =0;i < bb.length; i++) {
 bb[i].addEventListener('input', function(e){` заменить на  `Array.from(bb).forEach(function(e) {` `bb[i].addEventListener('input', function(e){` заменить на `bb.oninput = function() {`

Comment: Не, бро, не помогает! То мы заводили луп через ноды а ето через элементы , но разницы никакой

Comment: А может и правильно все, что то не так с моим кодом мб изначально . спс

Comment: В таком духе делать... Добавить внутри цикла проверку на предков и добавлять слушателя.

`var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (let i = 0; i < tags.length ; i++) {
    tags[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        console.log('element: ', e)
    })
}`